# bpy.utils.previews error

Tags: python

Hoping maybe a Blender dev can help with this. I have addons that load icons using the `bpy.utils.previews` module, but they give the following error

```
AttributeError: module 'bpy.utils' has no attribute 'previews'
```

The previews.py module exists in 2.7x/scripts/modules/bpy/utils. `bpy.utils.previews` only works for me in 2.78, not in 2.79 or 2.77/earlier.

Answer (score 6):

It seems that the previews module must be explicitly imported to be found:

`import bpy.utils.previews`

should be placed at the start of the file.